# Manually moving Eclipse Libraries to NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Im looking to move some of my Libraries from an Java Web Application currently in Eclipse to a new NetBeans Project

I can not use the source import tool as the original Eclipse Project I inherited was not set up correctly so this needs to be done manually.

In Eclipse my Libraries such as 'axis-ant.jar' and 'googleapi.jar' are stored in "Web-INF > lib"

Can I just copy past them into the Library folder in NetBeans? Is there a particular sub folder they should be in?

Currently my NetBeans Library folder has a JDK 1.6 folder and Apache Tomcat in it.

As always any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Just so the circumstances are available. I inherited a project which was not built in an IDE. While it is possible to do the same work manually it is best if there is a standard folder structure.  I was also not able to rebuild it in either NetBeans or Eclipse due to missing files.

My work around was to look up the proper folder structure for a WebApp especially the WEB-INF and try and to recreate it. For anyone facing the same issue you have to manually do this. Eclipse or NetBeans project import facilities just would not work.

In my case I was importing the libraries into the wrong folder, in the wrong location.